# htaccess rewrite rule fails on https redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

my htaccess look like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^login/?(.*)$ login.php$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^register/?(.*)$ register.php$1 [L]
```

i want to redirect my pages login and redirect to https and so i added the code below

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(login|register)/?$
RewriteRule .*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

so when i type **http**://www.xyz.com/login/ it redirects to **https**://www.xyz.com/login/ everything was fine when i decided to redirect the pages to http which are not login or register and i wrote

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(login|register)/?$
RewriteRule .*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

after that i testted the url **http**://www.xyz.com/login/ again and it redirects me to **https**://www.xyz.com/login.php

any idea to redirect **http**://www.xyz.com/login/ to **https**://www.xyz.com/login/ and on that page when i click the link **https**://www.xyz.com/news/1/ redirect to **http**://www.xyz.com/news/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this right below the `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(login|register)(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^(login|register) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

It also looks like you've pasted your rules wrong, the two blocks of rules are identical.

Comment: thanks for your answer and yes, the third code block is wrong. i tried your code and unfortunately it redirects me to **http**://www.xyz.com/**login.php** not **http**://www.xyz.com/login/

Comment: @ilazmi You have it before the 2 rules that rewrite `login` to `login.php`? It needs to be at the top of your rules